# Can I sell results from a GPL software

Tags: open-source, openfoam

My question is, Can I use GNU General Public License v3 software (in this specific case the OpenFOAM) to do consultancy? The source code will not be changed neither charged. The idea is just charging for the results given by the software.

Do I need a special authorization from Linux (OS) and/or OpenCFD Ltd (owner of the OpenFOAM Trademark) for using their software?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if you can use opensource tools to do consultancy bussiness? of course you can. The internet would close in minutes if it wasn't possible

Answer (score 1):

First: I am not a lawyer. With that in mind:

> Can I use GNU General Public License v3 software (in this specific case the OpenFOAM) to do consultancy?

Yes.

That is also part of the Free Software Foundation's [Free Software Definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html): The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0). And since the GNU GPL v3 gives you all four freedoms listed there, you are fine to do that.

> Do I need a special authorization from Linux (OS) and/or OpenCFD Ltd (owner of the OpenFOAM Trademark) for using their software?

No. You do not need special permission from them to use the software, that is to run the software on your computer(s). However, if "using the software" also includes modification of the source code **and** subsequent distribution of the modified program to the people you are consulting, you have to make sure they can get the modified source code, too.